# Password encryption problem in Rails Devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, devise

I am now currently changed to use the Gem Devise for user authentication. But I don't know how to match the encryption!

I knew that we could write a new encryptor and assign it in initializers, but the point is the encryptor accepts 4 arguments only (password, stretches, salt, pepper). But in my case, I do included the user's email and a customized salt in the encryption.

Is it possible to pass the user's email and customized salt into the encryptor?

ps. I am using database_authenticatable

Comment: why do you want to include the email and a customized salt instead of using the standard way?

Comment: It's long time ago and if I remember right my encryption before changing to devise used the email with another salt. So in order not to affect the users, we have to fine tune the encryption of devise so that it give the same result to match the original one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's sad that no one answered my question......

However, I think I've found the answer, although it's not as pretty as I imagined.

First, create the encryption class in the initializers:

```
module Devise
  module Encryptors
    class MySha1 < Base
      def self.digest(password, salt)
        Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("#{salt}-----#{password}")
      end

      def self.salt(email)
        Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("#{Time.now}-----#{email}")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Secondly, overwrite some methods in the User model:

```
# overwrite this method so that we call the encryptor class properly
def encrypt_password
  unless @password.blank?
    self.password_salt = self.class.encryptor_class.salt(email)
    self.encrypted_password = self.class.encryptor_class.digest(@password, self.password_salt)
  end
end

# Because when the database_authenticatable wrote the following method to regenerate the password, which in turn passed incorrect params to the encrypt_password, these overwrite is needed!
def password=(password)
  @password = password
end
def password_digest(pwd)
  self.class.encryptor_class.digest(pwd, self.password_salt)
end
```

And finally, we have to teach when to encrypt the password:

```
before_save :encrypt_password
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how old this is, but this seems like a better supported way of doing it: http://presentations.royvandewater.com/authentication-with-devise.html#9